# AgroUML how to generate UML diagram from java code

Tags: java, uml, argouml

I have a java project.How can i generate UML diagrams of that ptoject using AgroUML.

I downloaded agroUML but the UI is very confusing. I thought might be it will be something like import package and than generate UML diagram for that package.

Anybody has any idea about how to use AgroUML UI to generate UML diagrams if you already have source code.?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.34/ch03s04.html#tut.user.iface) would help, gives details of the ui and navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Generating UML diagrams out of existing java projects is mostly a very frustrating experience. The amount of complexity that is still easy to handle in a text-based project creates an enormous mess when displayed in the form of UML diagrams. If you want to improve your understanding of a java project, using [MOOSE](http://www.moosetechnology.org) provides a better way.